# Ideas for streaming OpenCV video feed via a web application

Tags: web-applications, opencv, computer-vision

I have the following setup, I have a robot with a single board computer that runs and navigates a certain path using opencv, robot also has a web server coupled with a simple jquery mobile based web app that allows me to change configuration options and viewing debug information but there is one piece of information that I can't figure out a reliable way to transfer which is what the robot actually sees. Currently what I am doing is I have one web page that retrieves the last processed frame which requires me to hit reload alot plus on mobile devices it is really slow. It has been at least 10 years since I have done any web programming so I was wondering what would be better way to stream these series of photos to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you already got the functionality to *display* your processed image on webpage, assuming you have done the header + boundary thing. 1 possible solution is to rewrite your current *display* module to append --boundary text for each *jpeg* (assuming you are using jpeg) and streaming them as *mjpg*. every modern browser can display motion jpeg.